# How Can I Add Subitem In Listview? (New On Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm Trying To Make An App With Names,Address And Other Details Using Listview Or Expandable Listview

[image: This Is My Screenshot Of My App]

So This Is My .xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.unicorninteractive.rssthsapp.studentname"
    android:background="#ff00f7">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Student Name"
    android:id="@+id/txtview_studentname"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv_studentnames"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_studentname" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And This My Java Code

```
package com.unicorninteractive.rssthsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class studentname extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_studentname);
    }

}
```

Thanks In Advance For Helping Me ^_^

Comment: There aren't `subitems` in the above picture. It's only 2 textviews in the same item. Google search: `android listview custom row`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class that extends ArrayAdapter,like this:

   ```
   public class ListSellerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourData>
   {
   LayoutInflater inflater;
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   }
   }
   ```

2.Inside the getView() methode of that adapter inflate a layout.

```
if(convertView==null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seller_detail,parent,false);
```

3.Inside that layout you can keep whatever items and sub items you need for your single data set.